# Данные не добавляются в FormData

Tags: javascript, formdata, redux-toolkit

Код где я пытаюсь добавить в result

{name: 'Screenshot_1.png', lastModified: 1699271345259, lastModifiedDate: Mon Nov 06 2023 14:49:05 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 610371, …}

либо 'null' так как он может принять строку, но в итоге ничего не добавляется туда, помогите!

```
var result = new FormData()

    result.append('key', 'null')
    console.log(result)
    createAppeal({
      attachment: result,
      order_id: selectedId,
      message: appealMessage,
      type: appealType,
      sum: appealSum,
    })
```